# having PHP/javascript create a website based on options picked

Tags: php, javascript

I want the user to be able to pick two different variables from a website (from a drop down menu) and hit a button to bring them to a page where files are to download based on the variables picked.

I have the html ready to go.. and i have both menus in an array in php.. i was wondering how to pass both variables through to another site and then have unique content depending on which ones picked..

how do i get php to make it's own site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

page1.php

```
<?php 
$ar = array('foo', 'bar');
?>
<form action="page2.php" method="post">
  <select name="choice">
    <?php foreach($ar as $value) { ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $value ?>"><?php echo $value ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="go to page2">
</form>
```

page2.php

```
<?php 
$choice = $_POST['choice']; // sanitize as needed
if( $choice === 'foo' ) {
  // do foo choice
} 
else if( $choice === 'bar' ) {
  // do bar choice
}
?>
```

Query strings are also ok, just change the form method to GET, and `$_POST` to `$_GET`.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using query variables? og perhaps posting the info to the page?
I would suggest using the query like: `http://www.yourdomain.com/speciallayoutpage.php?layout=2&colortheme=1`